# Excel return value or run calculation if criteria is not met. Formula needed

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

This is a fairly simply formula that I need syntax for. I do not know the syntax that Excel will accept.

Formula:
I want to return a value of "0" if the target cell has a value of "2" or less.
If the value is greater than "2" I want to multiply by "25".

I tried the below formula but my syntax is all wrong and am not sure where to look for correct syntax:

`=IF(B2<2,0),(B2>2, B2*25)`

Thank you for any help.

Comment: `IF(B2<=2, 0, B2*25)`

Comment: Gserg, I think it is missing some syntax... it isn't passing the logic test.

Comment: It might be, but it does exactly what your explanation says.

Comment: Gserg you were correct, for some reason my excel does not use commas to separate parts of a formula and instead wants "|" bars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note the proper syntax for the `IF()` function:

`IF(logical_test, value_if_true, [value_if_false])`

The `logical_test` is `B2 <= 2`.
The `value_if_true_` is `0`.
The `value_if_false` (*i.e.*, if `B2` is `> 2`) is `B2 * 25`.

So the formula is `=IF(B2<=2, 0, B2*25)`.

For example (data starting in `B2`, formula in `C2`):

```
        [B]     [C]
[2]     0       0
[3]     1       0
[4]     1.9     0
[5]     2       0
[6]     2.1     52.5
7       3       75
8       4       100
```

---

Follow-up from comments:

> How would I set this formula so the value couldn't go over a certain number... ie I don't want it to return values over 100 and instead set the value to 100 if it would be higher.

Now you want another `IF()` function as to evaluate what you do if B2 > 2:

`=IF(B2<=2, 0, IF(B2*25>100, 100, B2*25))`

Comment: So weird, I am putting this formula in and it is saying there is a problem with it. I know this is a super easy formula and I appreciate you explaining the if/then statement which I understand, but it keeps throwing an error on the first logic test. I opened up my Google drive and loaded the spreadsheet into Google Sheets and the formula works perfectly. Why is Excel not liking it even though it should work?

Comment: Hmmm, so the formula works if I use "|" bars instead of commas... must have a setting different.

Comment: Yes, it seems you have a regional setting or something governing your Excel syntax. I'm sure some Google searches would reveal what setting controls the formula argument separators.

Comment: How would I set this formula so the value couldn't go over a certain number... ie I don't want it to return values over 100 and instead set the value to 100 if it would be higher. Thanks a ton for your help!!!

Answer (score -1):

`if(b2<2,0,b2*25)`     <- should work

Comment: Yes, it works, but my Excel was not liking the commas and instead wanted bars "|".